# dynamically add listener to ajax created content in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, bind, listener

I am trying to get the html value of a linked clicked.
The links are created dynamically with Ajax so I don't think .bind will 
work and I don't have latest version with  .live

```
$('div#message').click(function() {
  var valueSelected = $(this).html();  // picks up the whole id. I juust want single href!          
  alert(valueSelected);
  return false;
});



<div id="message">
<br/>
<a class="doYouMean" href="#">location A</a>
<br/>
<a class="doYouMean" href="#">location B</a>
<br/>
<a class="doYouMean" href="#">location C</a>
<br/>
<a class="doYouMean" href="#">location D</a>
<br/>
<a class="doYouMean" href="#">location E</a>
<br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply your handler to just the links, in the callback of the AJAX load.

```
$('div#message').load( myUrl, function() {
    $('div#message a').click(function() {
       var valueSelected = $(this).html();
       alert(valueSelected);
       return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 16):

Here's an alternate approach that has not been mentioned:

If you're using **jQuery v1.7+** you can use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to bind an event listener to current HTML as well as HTML that is added in the future:

```
$('#message a').on('click', function(){
    alert('link clicked!');
});
```

If you are using an older version of jQuery, it is recommended you use the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method instead:

```
$('#message').delegate('a', 'click', function(){
    alert('link clicked!');
});
```

In summary:

```
$(elements).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(elements).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: I like this approach better than the first, because it gives you the option of using that event listener for both "regular" and ajax'd content. In the first answer, it assumes you only need that listener once.

Comment: Your method can't work with an asychrone div created... Just in case of div already exist

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options -

1. Use the LiveQuery plugin which is what we used before .live came along
2. Rebind your function to the click event after each successful ajax call. (Recommended)

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using the latest version if you can help it.

If it's the ".doYouMean" elements that are added using AJAX, and #message is always there, try:

```
$('#message').bind('click', function (event) {
  var target = event.currentTarget;
  if ($('.doYouMean').filter(target)) {
    // target is the .doYouMean that was clicked: Handle here
  };
});
```

(This works: http://www.jsfiddle.net/SuVzv/)

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is to make a function for click reinitialization, because you may have other situation, like i had :), so logic may be following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  initsomething();
});

function initsomething(){
  .......
  $('div#message').click(function() {
    var valueSelected = $(this).html();  // picks up the whole id. I juust want single href!          
    alert(valueSelected);
    return false;
  });
  .......
}
```

on ajax success run initsomething() :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a late and duplicate answer but This may be a late but this is what I do when I need ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document.body).on('click', '.Selector_S', function () { function_F(event, this) })
}

function function_F(event, d){
...do sth here...
}
```

And you dont need to reinitiate event listeners at all or write anything in ajax function.