# It works using div on body. It doesn't using get

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get, click

## Status: **WORKING**

### Runs smoothly - click works

**Jquery**

```
 $("document").ready(function(){

    $("#test").click(function(){
        alert("abc");
    });     
 });
```

**CSS**

```
.blue {
background-color:blue;
}
```

**Tag Body**

```
<body>
<div class="blue" id="test">Testing code</div>
</body>
```

## Status: **NOT WORKING**

### Succeeds to add the file and div `test` within it but click doesn't work

**Jquery**

```
 $("document").ready(function(){

    $.get("new.php", {
         // this math avoids IE from crashing
         nbRandom: Math.random() 
         },
         function(data){
         $("body").html(data);
         });

    $("#test").click(function(){
        alert("abc");
    });   
 });
```

**CSS**

```
.blue {
background-color:blue;
}
```

**Tag Body**

```
<body>
</body>
```

Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: the tag test is in  the file new.php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamically add listener to ajax created content in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552745/dynamically-add-listener-to-ajax-created-content-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should delegate the event, from one of static parents of the element or document object.

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", function(){
    alert("abc");
})
```

Comment: I used this one and it works the way I thought to code that way. I didn't know the way you said yet, as I'm just starting =) Thank you!!!

Answer (score 5):

The method `get` is asynchronous which means that the stream will continue while the ajax request is still running, the best solution is to put the click handler into the `get` callback.

```
$("document").ready(function(){

$.get("new.php", {
     // this math avoids IE from crashing
     nbRandom: Math.random() 
     },
     function(data){
       $("body").html(data);
       $("#test").click(function(){
         alert("abc");
       });   
     });


});
```

Comment: This would be a perfect answer with an explanation *why* this works and OP's code won't.

Answer (score 1):

use *delegate* or *on*(recommend)

```
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '#test', function() { alert('abc'); });
  // or
  // $('body').delegate('#test', function() { alert('abc'); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is the the `click` function is called before the `div` with `#test` is appended...

call click function after the div is appended.. so that it gets that id... and the event

try this

```
$.get("new.php", {
       // this math avoids IE from crashing
       nbRandom: Math.random() 
     },
     function(data){
        $("body").html(data);
        $("#test").click(function(){
            alert("abc");
        });
     });
```

**OR**

the `on` function with selector as `document`..(i alway prefer to go with this)

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", function(){
  alert("abc");
})
```

Comment: Thanks man! I was freaking out! hahahaha!
I used the first one, by the way.

Comment: @Th3B0Y: the second is better actually

Comment: I used the second one and it works the way I thought. I didn't know that way, as I'm just starting =) Thank you!!!