# Button Listener with jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, input, click

So my problem is, I want to run some jQuery-Code when the Button is clicked.

```
<input type="button" name="appointments_view" value="Alle Termine anzeigen" />
```

Here is my jQuery-Class (For testing, the Listener should print out something on the console.)

```
"use strict";

$.Class("View", {
init : function() {

    $("[name='appointments_view']").click(function() {
        console.log("appointments_view");
    });

}
});
```

If i run it in the browser, Firebug isn't giving me any errors. When i click the Button, nothing happens.

Putting the Listener in a $(document).ready() function doesn't help.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try `input[name='appointments_view']`

Comment: @Kweamod Does it bind if u put the click handler outside the $.Class() function? I know this is off topic, but what does $.Class do? Im not familiar with this syntax and would be happy if you could direct me to some docs. Googling for $.Class jquery didnt seem very helpful.

Comment: Did you call the init() method anywhere ?

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't find a proper documentation either. We just us this method in our class, and it works in other files! the init() function is like the constructor of a class, so it gets called everytime.

Comment: i have to say @lante's solution seems to work for me on Chrome.. Not sure why it wont work for u

Comment: Where exactly do i have to put lante's code in my code? I tried everything. I need the class though, because other classes use it.

Comment: Well, there is no $.Class in jQuery, it's some sort of custom method, and it's impossible for us to know how that method works without seeing it ?

Comment: we can only help if u tell us what this $.Class is or is meant to do. In all probabilty the problem is that ur not even doing  the binding  because the button selector and the listener are perfectly correct as proved by @lante. Are sure you dont need to call init() somehwre?

Comment: init() surely doesn't need to be called. Give me a few Minutes, i will try to find something about the $.Class.

Comment: @adeneo maybe this helps: http://glossar.hs-augsburg.de/beispiel/tutorium/html5_canvas/minipong/html5_canvas_minipong_01a_jquery/WebContent/js/ It's a JS project from my professor. He uses the $.Class   I will try to search for a better explanation, but i'm not sure if i will find one. Im just starting with JS, so i can't really tell you myself, what you want to know, i'm sorry.

Comment: If you look in the "lib" directory (go one directory up, to see it), maybe it gives you some clues, of what is happening here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem was, that the HTML was loaded with AJAX (the .load() function).
Although the .load() was written before (!) the listener, the button didn't respond.

The solution is, to write the listener in the callback-function of the .load()-function.

See here:

[dynamically add listener to ajax created content in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552745/dynamically-add-listener-to-ajax-created-content-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you put your function on `document.ready`?

```
$(function () {
    $("[name='appointments_view']").click(function() {
        console.log("appointments_view");
    });
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nescalante/qFZH5/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is $.Class(..)?? Are you trying to write a plugin or something. Tried running your code in Visual Studio and gave me the error object doesn't support this property. Applying it on jsFiddle gives another error. but keeping your code as regular script works. May be you can explain a bit more. Below is the jsFiddle link

```
$("[name='appointments_view']").click(function(){
//your code goes here.
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruchin/RsT6D/1/

Comment: maybe this helps: http://glossar.hs-augsburg.de/beispiel/tutorium/html5_canvas/minipong/html5_canvas_minipong_01a_jquery/WebContent/js/ It's a JS project from my professor. He uses the $.Class   I will try to search for a better explanation, but i'm not sure if i will find one. Im just starting with JS, so i can't really tell you myself, what you want to know, i'm sorry.

Comment: If you look in the "lib" directory (go one directory up, to see it), maybe it gives you some clues, of what is happening here...